# fill empty cells with todays date in powerbi modeling

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I have loaded a csv into power bi and am using the modeling tab to make the data how I want. I have a column that some have dates (M/D/YYYY) and some are empty. I would like to fill in the empty cells with todays date and leave the unempty cells as is.

I tried creating a new column and writing an if statement:
`Date = IF('Dataset'[Resolution Date] = BLANK(),'Dataset'[Resolution Date] = TODAY())`

However, it fills the entire new column with a Boolean, `False`.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's filling the cells with the result of your second argument:

```
'Dataset'[Resolution Date] = TODAY()
```

Since this equality is not true, it returns `False`.

Try it with just the `TODAY()` part and the date for when it's non-blank.

```
Date = IF('Dataset'[Resolution Date] = BLANK(), TODAY(), 'Dataset'[Resolution Date])
```

You can also use the `ISBLANK()` function instead.

```
Date = IF(ISBLANK('Dataset'[Resolution Date]), TODAY(), 'Dataset'[Resolution Date])
```